# I'm looking to get a highlight or an output of the new names from a list of incoming names from a Form response, compared to a list of names of usuals

Tags: google-sheets, match, vlookup, partial-matches

On Google Sheets, I have a form response with monthly new incoming names and a list with the names of usually inscribed people. I would like to identify with a function, new names that do not match any name in the usually inscribed list. For this I need a partial match because the list of usuals is composed with the first names only, but the form responses is composed by the full names and may change from month to month.

'Form responses 1'!B2:B contains the new incoming names list and 'Bridge'!A1:A contains the first names usually inscribed.

I have tried the functions match and vlookup but I cannot get a partial match for the second list.

I would need something that gives me the opposite result from this one

=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP("*"&Bridge!A1:A&"*",'Form responses 1'!B2:B,1,0))

since this one gives me the names of Bridge but I need the names of Form responses 1.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include sample data and an example of a successful outcome; please include the data _in_ the body of the question, and please do not use screenshots. There are several ways to create markdown tables, including the free online service at: [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)